# Filter the elements of one list with an other using Immutabel.js / functional JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutable.js

I have an array that contains **all** items and an other array that contains **selected** items. Then I want to create a third array **available** that consists of **all** except the elements contained in **selected**.

E.g

```
all = [1,2,3]
selected  = [3]
available =  [1,2]
```

How do I filter all and selected to create available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using `immutable.js`, the operation you're looking for is the `Set` class's [`.subtract()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set/subtract) method.

[in functional programming, the term "filter" normally means the operation of returning a new list from those elements on a source list that match a given predicate]

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for. Can you provide an example on how I use `.subtract()`? I'm lost on how to transform the array to a set which I can apply it on. :-|

Comment: I think you can just use `var s = new Set(array)` - and then use `toArray()` to turn the result back into an array again.  Can't test it because for some reason immutable won't load in my node.js environment.

Comment: Thanks! This works: `a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]; b = [ 3 ]; sa = Immutable.Set(a); sb = Immutable.Set(b); sa.subtract(sb)
Set { 1, 2 }`

Comment: I don't use `Set` very much, which isn't to say it's wrong. In case anyone is interested here is an example using `Lists` and filters. http://codepen.io/toddmoore/pen/zrPyQv?editors=001

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```js
var array1= [1, 2, 3];
    var array2= [3];
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length ; i++) {
  
    var result=false;
    for (var n = 0; n < array2.length ; n++) {
         if (array2[n] === array1[i]) {
            result=true;
          }
          
          
        }
        if(!result)
        {
        results.push(array1[i]);
        }
    }
    
    console.log(results);
```

Comment: not mine, but the `O(n^2)` algorithm which fails to terminate early on match is probably part of the reason.  Another would be not using the same input data as the OP (strings instead of numbers) and using `==` instead of `===`.  It's also not "functional" (nor using immutable.js) per the OP's subject line.

Comment: @Alnitak Makes sense, I had no idea about that. Also, I didn't notice `immutable` part.